# Git: Changes done directly into a working directory (linked to a bare repository)

Tags: git

I have a setup on a server containing a bare repository that checks out code to a working directory when code is pushed to it.

I had to edit some files directly in the working directory on the server. Thus, those changes are not committed into the bare repository and I can't pull them to my local machine.

Here is what I tried (and what I didn't)

1. Commiting will not work on the working repo as far as I know since it does not have a .git directory inside it (meaning that since it's not git init-ialized - so I can't do that
2. Doing the commit command on the bare repo won't work either IMO because well I remember reading something on SO that bare repos are not meant for committing directly. Instead you only push code to them. You can't commit because they don't have the code to commit in them.
3. I can't think of any other way those changes on the working directory could be identified as a commit in the bare repo.

I tried searching for this on StackOverflow but couldn't get the answer. Maybe not using the correct GIT terminology since I'm just learning GIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DileepNimantha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50670133/1256452) is mostly correct (it's missing a step, at least at the time I write this), but there are several potentially-easier ways.  We'll get to the easiest one later; let's start out with what we're really doing.  I'll add that the missing step is to run `git fetch` and `git read-tree` (see below) after `git remote add ...`.  There's also an assumption that the current branch `master` is correct.

The fundamental issue is the one you've identified: you have a bare repository (with `core.bare = true`, `git init --bare`, etc.) which therefore has no work-tree.

To make a *new commit* in any Git repository, you technically don't need a work-tree at all.  What you need is for your *index* (also known as your *staging-area* or sometimes your *cache*) associated with that repository to have the correct file contents.  The standard way to do this, though, is using `git add file1 file2 ...`, which copies the given files from your work-tree into your index, overwriting the old versions of those files in the index.  This of course *does* need a work-tree.

A bare repository, despite having no work-tree, still has an index.  Here's how we can bypass the lack of a work-tree.

You can fill the index from a specific commit, such as the tip of `master`, using `git read-tree`:

```
$ git read-tree master
```

You can then replace one of the index entries from a file in the file system.  In this case, I updated `sig.py` by extracting it to a file in the file system that is now in /tmp, and then edited it there:

```
$ git hash-object -w -t blob /tmp/sig.py
b6a42a1dd3fff08aa4bed6b054b310f69ed518c1
```

It's now necessary to produce the `git ls-files` stage entry for that file.  The old one is:

```
$ git ls-files --stage sig.py
100644 7e49ad4f1042b14e088571a091a7b9f7d1010b4c 0       sig.py
```

We don't need to use the stage number since `git update-index` allows us to skip it, so we can print the new hash with the rest of the appropriate information directly:

```
$ printf '%s %s %s\t%s\n' 100644 blob \
    b6a42a1dd3fff08aa4bed6b054b310f69ed518c1 sig.py | \
    git update-index --index-info
```

I've split this up into three lines, two with backslash-newline, for posting length purposes.  It's really all one command, but when expressed this way as shell input, it will work just as well.  Note that the new blob hash is the one we got by writing the new updated file into the repository.  (Side note: we have about 14 days to finish our work once we start this process, before `git gc` declares our newly-created blob object to be unused, and therefore prunes it.)

We now need to write the index as a *tree* object:

```
$ git write-tree
e92275076a62ca850b0bda3f6c3603632b4a6cce
```

and then store this tree as a commit object.  Let's make this a new commit that we'll add after the current tip of `master`:

```
$ git commit-tree -p master \
    -m 'make signal handler work in py2k and py3k' \
    e92275076a62ca850b0bda3f6c3603632b4a6cce
```

Running this produced, for me, the commit hash:

```
e068bdfce2fd992dc396cb4969327ef5c4d39a43
```

We now need to make some branch name, perhaps a new one, refer to this commit hash.  I'll use a new one rather than updating `master` in place:

```
$ git branch fix-signal e068bdfce2fd992dc396cb4969327ef5c4d39a43
```

We can now see whether this worked by running `git log` in this bare repository:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate -n 2 fix-signal
e068bdf (fix-signal) make signal handler work in py2k and py3k
11ae6ca (HEAD -> master) add run-checks script
```

Let's view the change as a patch:

```
$ git show fix-signal
[snip]
index 7e49ad4..b6a42a1 100644
--- a/sig.py
+++ b/sig.py
@@ -5,7 +5,10 @@ import sys
 import time

 def signal_handler(signum, frame):
-    os.write(1, bytes('caught sig %d\n' % signum, 'iso8859-1'))
+    if str is not bytes:
+        os.write(1, bytes('caught sig %d\n' % signum, 'iso8859-1'))
+    else:
+        os.write(1, 'caught sig %d\n' % signum)

 def catch_by_sig():
     old_int = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

But this really is a `--bare` repository:

```
$ git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

#### Making it easier

The `git` front-end command takes many options that appear *before* the verb.  For instance, if your extracted work-tree on the server lives in `/tmp/work`, you can, on the server, `cd` to your Git repository:

```
$ cd ...
```

and then run:

```
$ git --work-tree=/tmp/work status
```

and get status output.  **Note that `git status` compares the HEAD commit with the current index contents, and then the current index contents with the work-tree.**  Since your main Git repository here is a `--bare` repository, its index *might not* match the contents of your `/tmp/work` directory at all.  (Depending on how you have your server deploy pushes, the index for that Git repository may be non-empty.  You must decide whether you care what is in it.)

If necessary, you can use a `git read-tree` operation, just as we did in the longer form above, to fill the index from some specific commit.  You can name the commit by its branch name, as I did above, or by its hash ID: the key is to fill the index *from* the commit that's currently deployed into the deployment-area.

Now that the index is filled in a way to match (mostly) the deployment area, except for the modified files, you can run:

```
git --work-tree=/tmp/work add file1.ext file2.ext
```

for instance, to add those files from the work-tree (you will do this while "cd"-ed into the Git repository).  You can then run:

```
git --work-tree=/tmp/work commit
```

as usual.  **Note that this will commit on the current branch,** i.e., the one that `HEAD` is attached to in the repository.  That's probably correct because of any deployment script you're using.

Essentially, each time you run a Git command, you tell it: *ignore the `core.bare` setting, there is a work-tree over in this other path.*  In fact, that's probably how your deployment-during-push-operation hook works.

I don't recommend doing this as normal practice—you're getting all the cost of allowing pushes to a non-bare repository, with none of the benefits, so you might as well just set up a non-bare repository instead of doing this kind of mucking-about.  But as a quick hack around an emergency, it works.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of the git concepts. I'm currently re-reading to understand it. I'm having trouble following through the concepts because I'm a newbie at git. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: One question though: Would it be possible to do `git remote add ... ` a on a working directory which is already a remote of a bare repository? That would mean effectively remote-adding the directory to itself (at least in my case) which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Let's back this up for a moment first. *Work-trees* are not remotes of anything, they're just work-trees. They are just places in which you do your work. There's one work-tree *attached to* any Git repository, unless it's a `--bare` one. When you clone a Git repository, you get a separate, now-independently-controlled *new* Git repository. The new clone, being a repository, has its own work-tree. So your clone on your own machine is separate from the clone on the server.

Comment: What a *remote* like `origin` is, is just a *name for a URL*. If you connect *to* that URL, calling it up over a network connection for instance, presumably a Git repository answers. So, when your own PC has a Git repository, and in that Git repository you set the name `origin` to mean `ssh://server.example.com/path/to/repo.git`, you're saying that *your* Git can dial `ssh://server...` and get another Git. Your Git and that Git can then *share commits*.

Comment: Work-trees are completely irrelevant to this sharing process. The `git fetch` and `git push` operations do the sharing. Work-trees come back into the picture either before or after the sharing: if you got new commits from them, you might want to `git checkout` those commits into your work-tree, so that you can see (and work on) the files contained within those commits.

Comment: I completely understand your last three comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172357/discussion-between-torek-and-navkarj).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can commit your code from your working directory. You should simply initiate this as a git repository. Try following:

1. `git init`
2. `git remote add origin <your git url>`
3. `git add` your changes and commit and push to your repository.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Please reread my question. The working directory is located on the server and is different from the local repository on my PC. I've already done the commands you've specified above on the local repo on my PC.

Comment: Can you do this on the server? And push to the repository, so you can pull the changes to your local directory.

Comment: That will be adding the working directory itself as its remote. Do you think that can work?

Comment: Yeah something like that. But remote is GitHub or Bitbucket repo. You can set that as the remote to your working directory.